# Page number in page which contain the name of the chapter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to insert in each page the chapter name and number (bottom right)
The problem is that this configuration does not apply to pages that contain the name of the chapter!
My code :

```
 \usepackage[fit]{truncate}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\truncate{.95\headwidth}{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
```

Comment: In the footer ("bottom right")? Your code snippet uses `\leftmark` in the header... Which is it? Also what document class are you using? Do you have any restrictions in terms of packages?

Comment: I use :

    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
the problem is that: in all pages, the page number is centered except the pages that contain the title of the chapters and parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`titleps` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) provides easy access to sectional titles and is a viable alternative to using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

You can define a new page style (say `main`) and issue that at every start-of-chapter page, or redefine `plain` to include the details you want - `plain` is the default page style associated with the first page of a chapter.

Here's a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,titleps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,titleps}
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  % Header rule: \setheadrule
  % Footer rule: \setfootrule
  % Header: \sethead{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{\@chapapp~\thechapter\ \chaptertitle}% \setfoot{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}\thispagestyle{main}\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Redefining `plain` would resemble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
  % Header rule: \setheadrule
  % Footer rule: \setfootrule
  % Header: \sethead{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{\@chapapp~\thechapter\ \chaptertitle}% \setfoot{<left>}{<centre>}{<right>}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thank you. 
it works well, except at the end, kile display a file "ttlps" and it points to the following two lines :
\newcommand\headrule{\setheadrule{.4\p@}}
\newcommand\footrule{\setfootrule{.4\p@}}

Comment: @physics: Can you provide more detail? Are you using `titleps` or `ttlps`? Also, you should use *only* `titleps`. Not that *and* `fancyhdr`.

Comment: I did not insert the line: 
    \usepackage{lipsum,titleps}
Is it interesting?

Comment: @physics: You absolutely need `\usepackage{titleps}`, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was just for the above example and provides dummy text.